# Ember.js Asynchronous Object Parameter

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, ember.js

I am having some issues with Ember.js and loading resources asynchronously (aka I don't know what I'm doing). This is what I have. It currently doesn't update the `list` parameter after receiving the data. The template does not render anything. Thanks for any help.

**Utilities**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export var page = Ember.Object.extend({
  type: null,

  list: Ember.computed('type', function() {
    var type = this.get('type');
    var url = "/test/" + type + "/test2";

    if (type) {
      getArray(url).then(function(list) {
        return list;
      });
    } else {
      return [];
    }
  })
});

export function get(url) {
  return Ember.$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'text',
        cache: true,
    xhrFields: {
         withCredentials: true
    }
  });
}

export function getArray(url) {
  return get(url).then(
    function(file) {
      var array = file.split("\n");
      array.pop();
      return array;
    },
    function() {
      return ["Error!"];
    }
  );
}
```

**Route**

```
import util from 'app/utils/utilities';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model(params) {
    var p = util.page.create({
      type: params.log_type
    });

    return p;
  }
});
```

**Template**

```
{{#each model.list as |item|}}
  <li><a href="{{item}}">{{item}}</a></li>
{{/each}}
```

Comment: Do you get any errors on your browser console? Can you show us what `file` data looks like?

Comment: computed properties wont resolve like this. You could however use promiseObject to achieve what you want. discuss.emberjs.com/t/computed-property-on-async-property/7176. Or promiseArray for array .s

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the following part of your code:

```
if (type) {
  getArray(url).then(function(list) {
    return list;
  });
} else {
  return [];
}
```

This is not going to do what you think it does. `return list` returns `list` as the value of the promise, but you are not then doing anything with that promise. In particular, be clear that the computed property `list` will not take on that value. When the `if (type)` branch is taken, the computed property `list` will have the value `undefined` (since it's not returning anything in that case).

Remember that `model` wants you to return a promise (at least, if you want it to do its thing, which is to wait for the promise to resolve, then proceed with the transition, then use the resolved value of the promise to call `afterModel` and `setupController` etc.) Therefore, instead of making `list` a computed property, make it a regular method which returns a promise for the `model` hook on your route to consume:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export var page = Ember.Object.extend({
  type: null,

  list: function() {
    var type = this.get('type');
    var url = "/test/" + type + "/test2";

    if (!type) return [];
    return getArray(url);
});
```

Then in your route

```
import util from 'app/utils/utilities';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model(params) {
    var p = util.page.create({
      type: params.log_type
    });

    return p.list();
  }
});
```

Your model will then be the list, so in the template:

```
{{#each model as |item|}}
  <li><a href="{{item}}">{{item}}</a></li>
{{/each}}
```